# Best Performance for Importing <head> Tag Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to determine the best way to go about importing a head.html file into the `<head>` tag for every webpage. I want to do this so that all resources are located in one file, to minimize bloat in other files, and also to provide an import for the header/footer on every page.

**head.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/sample.png">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Andada" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
     $(function () {
         $("header").load("header.html");
         $("footer").load("footer.html");
     });
 </script>
```

I've already considered JavaScript loading, but it's bad practice to import a JavaScript file right off the bat. Running the site through [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), it's suggested that you "[Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)".

**index.html head tag w/ JavaScript**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> <!-- Blocking JavaScript -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("head").load("head.html");
        });
    </script>
<head>
```

I've also tried using HTML imports. This seems to work alright on desktop, other than the fact that an import brings in a full HTML document when rendered, wrapping the contents of my file in `<html><head><body>` tags. This is annoying and it is non-functional on my Android phone.

**Rendered index.html head tag w/ HTML import**

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="head.html">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Sample</title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/sample.png">

            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Andada" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("header").load("header.html");
                    $("footer").load("footer.html");
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</head>
```

Comment: You don't have `header` and `footer` tags in your html.

Comment: I do, I've only included the `<head>` tag portion of my html document because that's the relevant part.

Comment: Are we talking about `<head>` or `<header>` tags?

Comment: `<head>` tags. My header and footer imports work fine, that's a non-issue.

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: FYI, regarding: `it's suggested that you "Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript".` - You can make javascript load non-blocking (use the async attribute)

Comment: Using JS is just a bad idea for loading the head element's contents. For example, the parser is not going to be able to read your `charset=ISO-8859-1` instruction, so it's pot luck what character set it'll use.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is a terrible way to load the header content!!

You should be looking at `PHP` if you save your `.html` documents as `.php`
Then include these into the page using PHP includes in your `index.php` files.

index.php example:

```
<?
  include('header.php');

   <div>body content here</div>

 include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid PHP if possible, because it's my understanding that the hosting sever needs to support it.

Comment: Why would you avoid PHP include, using jQuery will dramatically decrease the performance overall.

Comment: @Danielle Get a different host if PHP is not working, Javascript workaround is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon what server-side language your server is running.  If it's php, then do

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include('path_to_file/head.php'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could also use include_once, require, or require_once instead.  If your server is running something other than php, then you will have to use whatever the equivalent is in its language.  If you have no access to the server and are running a completely static site, like off of Dropbox, Google Drive, or S3, then the best option I know of, if you have only a small amount of content, is to not include files but just run everything off of one base page with content that is hidden and displayed with javascript.